# Iteration of JSON not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I received a response from MY ajax as follows

```
"{\"analgesicTax\":false,\"unitPriceRequired\":false,\"toConsumer\":true,\"toRetailer\":true,\"taxName\":\"1\"}"
```

After calling `JSON.parse(result)`, the result looks like

```
{"analgesicTax":false, "unitPriceRequired":false, "toConsumer":true, "toRetailer":true, "taxName":"1"}
```

Up until that point everything seems to be ok.  However, when I tried to print my key/value pairs by using following code

```
 var data =  JSON.parse(result);
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.analgesicTax);
                    for (var prop in data) {
                    console.log(prop+"is" + data[prop]);
```

I tried both using with and without `JSON.parse()` but the output is same as follows.

```
0is{
1is"
2isa
3isn
4isa
5isl
6isg
7ise
8iss
9isi
10isc
11isT
12isa
13isx
14is"
15is:
16isf
17isa
18isl
19iss
20ise
21is,
22is"
23isu
24isn
25isi
26ist
27isP
28isr
29isi
30isc
31ise
32isR
33ise
34isq
35isu
36isi
37isr
38ise
39isd
40is"
41is:
42isf
43isa
44isl
45iss
46ise
47is,
48is"
49ist
50iso
51isC
52iso
53isn
54iss
55isu
56ism
57ise
58isr
59is"
60is:
61ist
62isr
63isu
64ise
65is,
66is"
67ist
68iso
69isR
70ise
71ist
72isa
73isi
74isl
75ise
76isr
77is"
78is:
79ist
80isr
81isu
82ise
83is,
84is"
85ist
86isa
87isx
88isN
89isa
90ism
91ise
92is"
93is:
94is"
95is1
96is"
97is}
```

It seems to me that rather than treat it like a JSON object, it is handling as a string array.  Any Inputs?

Comment: **[works good for me](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zve95e7t/)**

Comment: By the output looks like `data` is a string and not an object. And by your first code it looks like you have a string of json text instead of just json text, something similar to `'"{}"'` instead of `'{}'` note single quotes surrounding double quotes. Which means you just end up with a regular string after the first parse. You could try double parsing it: `JSON.parse( JSON.parse(result) )` but would suggest finding out why you are getting it as you are and fixing that first

Comment: I hope, you get this data using Ajax. Please confirm whether Ajax has the dataType param.

Comment: @PatrickEvans  actually double parsing it would be detrimental since the first parse will create the JSON object.  The reason why the string looks _peculiar_ is because the string terminator is the double quote.  So any double quotes inside the string need to be escaped with a backslash character `\"`.

Comment: @estinsunny dataType as text. As this ajax can return a string or an json

Comment: Please change it into JSON. Probably you will get an error. If so, please correct the format of JSON from the server side.

Comment: We have 2 scenarios either it will send me a url or it will send me an json object.If I keep the datatype as JSON then how I need to handle for url.

Comment: @sree you will need an if condition to test if it's a url or json prior to processing it.

Comment: @user9263373 how can I add it?

Comment: @sree add it to the beginning of the success handler of your ajax call.  Inspect the value to determine if it's a url or JSON represented as a string.  If you determine it's JSON represented as a string, then call `JSON.parse()` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

If the `result` is already JSON, then you don't want to use `JSON.parse()` since `JSON.parse()` converts a string representation of JSON into an object.  Simply run your for loop as you coded and you should be able to get all the keys and their values.

However, if you do start out with a string representation of a JSON object, that's when you want to use `JSON.parse()`.

```js
//Starting with a JSON object
var result = {
  "analgesicTax": false,
  "unitPriceRequired": false,
  "toConsumer": true,
  "toRetailer": true,
  "taxName": "1"
}

for (var prop in result) {
  console.log(prop + " is " + result[prop]);
}

console.log('');

//Starting with JSON represented as a string
var result = "{\"analgesicTax\":false,\"unitPriceRequired\":false,\"toConsumer\":true,\"toRetailer\":true,\"taxName\":\"1\"}";

var data = JSON.parse(result);

for (var prop in data) {
  console.log(prop + " is " + data[prop]);
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well.But the same response like a string object

Comment: @sree I edited my response.  I show the code both ways.  One starting with a JSON object and one starting with a string representation of a JSON object.  It's actually the same string you posted in your code example.

Comment: I tried both the ways and still the output is same as mentioned in the ticket.I have printed the out json object in console and copied across.Is that original response has special characters not showing in the console?.If So,How can I print with the special characters in console?

Comment: @sree  Did you run the code snippet?  It shows the output as you would expect.  It doesn't show the _special characters_ you described in your question.

Comment: Yes checked it.the same code with dynamic result it is number and character.but when I print the result its showing as exactly same as the one in the code snippet

Comment: @sree so when you run the code snippet here in Stack Overflow, it doesn't display the expected result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164802/discussion-between-user9263373-and-sree).

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var data =  JSON.parse(result);
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
console.log(data[key]);
});
```

Comment: tried and result is same as mentioned in the ticket

Comment: if result is already json, then don't parse it again and then try